# Bootstrap: How to close an open collapsed navbar when clicking outside of the MENU?

Tags: html, jquery, dropdown

I want to have my menu closed when the user clicks outside the menu, not only outside the navbar element. Because I have more collapses in my menu, this solution did not work for me: [How to close an open collapsed navbar when clicking outside of the navbar element in Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23764863/how-to-close-an-open-collapsed-navbar-when-clicking-outside-of-the-navbar-elemen)
The menu disapeares when I click outside the menu, but when I click on the link with a dropdown, the whole menu collapses.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-mobile" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="list-group panel">
            <a href="#submenu-1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Webshop</a>
            <ul class="collapse" id="submenu-1">
                <a href="#SubMenu1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Industriële verpakkingen</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item">Promotionele verpakkingen</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item">Gelamineerde verpakkingen</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item">Enveloppen &verzend verpakkingen</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item">Medische verpakkingen</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item">Co-packing</a>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or bootply of this

Comment: post the rest of your html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this to collapse if not clicking a link: **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/km8zojLe/)**

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('a')) {
        $('.collapse').collapse('hide');        
    }
});
```

Comment: I fixed the issue by adding navbar- to .collapse. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can add the class `in` to the `collapse` to keep hidden ;)

Comment: when clicking on the search <input> field, the menu hides... how can I fix this?

Comment: add another condition to this like so: `if (!$(e.target).is('a') && !$(e.target).is('input')) { ...`

Comment: I have got this working but when I click a sub menu link and it opens a modal window it also closes the submenu.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

another alternative, you can add code below :

```js
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".list-group ").hover(            
  function() {
   $('.collapse', this).stop( true, true ).slideDown("fast");
   $(this).toggleClass('open');        
  },
  function() {
   $('.collapse', this).stop( true, true ).slideUp("fast");
   $(this).toggleClass('open');       
  }
  );
 });
</script>
```

another example : [dtc-eng](http://dtc-eng.blogspot.co.id/2015/12/dropdown-menu-with-bootsrap.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on this:

```js
$(document).on('click', function(event){
  var $clickedOn = $(event.target),
      $collapsableItems = $('.collapse'),
      isToggleButton = ($clickedOn.closest('.navbar-toggle').length == 1),
      isLink = ($clickedOn.closest('a').length == 1),
      isOutsideNavbar = ($clickedOn.parents('.navbar').length == 0);

  if( (!isToggleButton && isLink) || isOutsideNavbar ) {
    $collapsableItems.each(function(){
      $(this).collapse('hide');
    });
  }
});
```

This solution handles:

- single page website/applications (and will work on multi-pages too).
- clicks on:

  - `.navbar-toggle` elements (could be `<buttons>` or `<a>`, and it handles clicks on potential inner elements like `<span>` or `<strong>` or whatever).
  - on simple `<a>` elements (again, it handles clicks on inner elements).
  - just outside some particular parent (ie. `.navbar`).
- multiple collapsable (`.collapse`) elements that might be open (indistinct to where they are placed in the DOM).

Not enough for you? No problem. You can customize most of the selectors passed to jQuery (`document`, `.collapse`, `.navbar`, etc) to suit your needs or even add more conditions.