# How to close a boostrap collapse whenever a user scroll down or coutside the collapse

Tags: javascript, css

This is what I'm currently using to trigger it
    GET FREE QUOTE
then this is the html code

```
<div id="demo" class="collapse">
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div class="wrap-type-input">
        <form id="get_free_quote" class="contact-form" method="post" action="contact/contact-process.php">        
            <div class="input-wrap name">
                <input type="text" value="" tabindex="1" placeholder="Name (*)" name="name" id="name" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="input-wrap name">
                <input type="text" min="0" value="" accept="*/phone" tabindex="1" placeholder="Phone (*)" name="phone" id="name" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="input-wrap email">
                <input type="email" value="" tabindex="2" placeholder="Email (*)" name="email" id="email" required="">
            </div>  
            <div class="textarea-wrap">
                <textarea class="type-input" tabindex="3" placeholder="Items you Need" name="message" id="message-contact" required=""></textarea>
            </div>  
            <div class="subscribe">
                <button type="submit" id="submit" class="button" name="submit">Send Message</button>
            </div> 
        </form>                          
    </div>
</div>
```

I will really be grateful for an answer

Comment: Share more code or us to understand more

Comment: put demo on jsfiddle and be specific while asking question

Comment: Well my question does not involve any programming codes. All I simply want is to close a Bootstrap Collapse whenever a user clicks outside it Thanks

Comment: then check this answer :/    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23764863/how-to-close-an-open-collapsed-navbar-when-clicking-outside-of-the-navbar-elemen