# How to close responsive bootstrap 4 menu when clicking outside

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

On desktop, clicking outside of my bootstrap nav menu closes it. However this behaviour does not work on mobile.

I've tried to edit some code from a codepen to reference the relevant classes on my website, to no avail.

Here is the code I've used:

```
const $menu = $('#id-of-menu');

$(document).mouseup(e => {
   if (!$menu.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
   && $menu.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
   {
     $menu.removeClass('show');
  }
 });
```

I'd hoped that clicking outside the menu would remove the 'show' class from the menu, thereby hiding it. In practice though, nothing happens.

**SOLUTION**

The answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23764863/how-to-close-an-open-collapsed-navbar-when-clicking-outside-of-the-navbar-elemen) by Henrywright solved my problem (obviously after changing relevant class and id names).

This is the eventual code I used:

```
jQuery('body').bind('click', function(e) {
    if(jQuery(e.target).closest('.navbar').length == 0) {
        // click happened outside of .navbar, so hide
        var opened = jQuery('#id-of-menu').hasClass('show');
        if ( opened === true ) {
            jQuery('#id-of-menu').collapse('hide');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function onMenuClick(){
    $('#id-of-menu').collapse('hide');
}
```

Add this in your menu items:

```
onclick="onMenuClick()"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is this designed to collapse the menu when the user clicks anywhere on the page?

Comment: You can add onMenuClick() on any event you want. But I would simply add them to the menu item links to get the efffect you want.

Comment: I'd like the menu to close whenever the user clicks anywhere on the page when it is open, not just when they click on the menu items.

Answer (score -1):

'mouseup' event is not present on mobile devices, try 'click'

Comment: Just tried that: no luck. I replaced 'mouseup' verbatim with 'click'.

Comment: perhaps something around detecting the target? do you have a working code for this, or can you setup a codesandbox or jsfiddle or something to help seeing the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your help Peter. I'm about to comment with a solution I found.