# Bootstrap: Jquery: NavBar: Collapse all links including dropdown toggle

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap navbar as follows:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header nav-tabs" style="border-bottom:none;">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="padding-top:20px">
           <li>
        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Information&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="/Home/Terms">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/Home/Privacy">Privacy Policy</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/Home/ContactUs">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I collapse the menu when clicked outside the navbar menu as follows:

```
$("body").on('click', function(event){
    var container = $(".navbar");    
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
        container.collapse('hide');
    }
});
```

When clicked outside, the dropdown menu links collapse; but, how do I collapse the "Information"(dropdown-toggle) link too?
Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Looked at the post
[How to close an open collapsed navbar when clicking outside of the navbar element in Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23764863/how-to-close-an-open-collapsed-navbar-when-clicking-outside-of-the-navbar-elemen)

The solution seems to work for me in Bootstrap Compiler, but, it collapses the menu even if I click inside the navbar. How do I solve that issue?

```
$(document).click(function (event) {
    var clickover = $(event.target);
    var _opened = $(".navbar-collapse").hasClass("navbar-collapse collapse in");
    //if (_opened === true && !clickover.hasClass("navbar-toggle")) {
    if (_opened === true && !clickover.hasClass("navbar-toggle")) {            
        $("button.navbar-toggle").click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/76egsryq/) see if that works for you or not .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://dotnetfiddle.net/qMDjF5

View

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index23</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#theButton").css("display", "none");
            $(document).click(function (event) {
                var target = $(event.target);
                if (target.is("html")) {
                    $(".dropdown-toggle").css("visibility", "hidden");
                    $(".navbar-toggle").css("display", "none")
                    $("#theButton").css("display", "block");
                }
                else if (!target.is("button")) {
                    alert("You need to View in Full Screen, so you can click in the body, which is below the Navigation. You clicked " + event.target.nodeName)
                }
            });
            $("#theButton").click(function () {
                $(".dropdown-toggle").css("visibility", "visible");
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header nav-tabs" style="border-bottom:none;">
                <button id="theButton">Toggle navigation</button>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    Toggle navigation
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="padding-top:20px">
                    <li>
                        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            Information&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="/Home/Terms">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/Home/Privacy">Privacy Policy</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/Home/ContactUs">Contact Us</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```