# Collapse Nav menu when body is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, navigation

Using JQuery, I want to be able to collapse my navigation by clicking elsewhere on the page (anything that isnt the burger). I think  I understand the logic, but just fail to make it work.

Please see the following JFiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/ywkxyjx3/33/

This is the logic I have so far:

```
$(".burger").click(function() {
  $(".nav").toggleClass("show", 900); // toggles on .show css
  $(".burger").toggleClass("change"); // toggles on .change css for hamburger animation
});

$('body').click(function(event){ //onBodyclick
  if ($(!event.target).closest('.navCont').length) { //if click isnt 
navCont or any child elements then..
    return; //do nothing
  } else {
    // do something when not targeted
  }
});
```

After some research I have found similar questions but I am failing to apply it to my own, self built navigation.

[How to hide my collapse bootstrap 3 navbar with click on body when, collapse is visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240594/how-to-hide-my-collapse-bootstrap-3-navbar-with-click-on-body-when-collapse-is)

[How to close an open collapsed navbar when clicking outside of the navbar element in Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23764863/how-to-close-an-open-collapsed-navbar-when-clicking-outside-of-the-navbar-elemen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the code below.

```js
$(".burger").click(function() {
  $(".nav").toggleClass("show", 900);
  $(".burger").toggleClass("change");
});

$('body').click(function(event){
  if ($(!event.target).closest('.navCont').length) {
    return; //do nothing
  } else {
   // do something when not targeted
  }
});

$('html').click(function() {
   $(".nav").removeClass("show", 900);
   $(".burger").removeClass("change");
});

$('#navCont').click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
#navCont {
  width: 47px;
  height: auto;
  float: right;
}


/*Dropdown Nav*/

.nav {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 0px;
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 55px;
  opacity: 99;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.nav a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.show {
  height: auto;
}

.burger {
  /* box around hamburger. Has onclick function*/
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*Individual lines of burger*/

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 36px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #95449a;
  margin: 6px 0;
  /*seperate the lines*/
  transition: 1s;
  /*time taken for any animation to take place */
}


/*in html classlist.toggle(change)*/

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10px) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateY(10px) rotate(45deg);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(10px);
  transform: translateX(10px);
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navCont">
  <div class="burger">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="#">Placeholder1</a>
    <a href="#">Placeholder2</a>
    <a href="#">Placeholder3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont want the navigation to open when body is clicked. I will take a look at this example in greater detail when I arrive home. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(".burger").click(function(event) {
  $(".nav").toggleClass("show", 900);
  $(".burger").toggleClass("change");
  event.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function(event) { 
   if($('.change').length){
      $(".nav").toggleClass("show", 900);
      $(".burger").toggleClass("change");
  }
});
```

```css
#navCont {
  width: 47px;
  height: auto;
  float: right;
}


/*Dropdown Nav*/

.nav {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 0px;
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 55px;
  opacity: 99;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.nav a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.show {
  height: auto;
}

.burger {
  /* box around hamburger. Has onclick function*/
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*Individual lines of burger*/

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 36px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #95449a;
  margin: 6px 0;
  /*seperate the lines*/
  transition: 1s;
  /*time taken for any animation to take place */
}


/*in html classlist.toggle(change)*/

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10px) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateY(10px) rotate(45deg);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(10px);
  transform: translateX(10px);
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navCont">
  <div class="burger">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="#">Placeholder1</a>
    <a href="#">Placeholder2</a>
    <a href="#">Placeholder3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here's my thinking.

```
$(".burger").click(function(event) {

   // Added this to make sure $('body').click doesn't override open nav function
   event.stopPropagation() 

   $(".nav").toggleClass("show", 900);
   $(".burger").toggleClass("change");
});

// then when you click the body, it checks to see whether or not it is already open, if it is, close it.

$('body').click(function(){
  if ($(".nav").hasClass('show') && $(".burger").hasClass('change') ) {
    $(".nav").toggleClass("show", 900);
    $(".burger").toggleClass("change");
  } 
})
```